# Fast 2D integral coordinate to custom class dictionary collection in C#

Tags: c#, optimization, collections

I need a fast collection that maps 2D int-typed point to custom class in C#.

The collection needs to have:

- Fast lookup (coords to custom class), adding a point if it does not exist
- Fast remove range of key-point (outside of given rect). This actually rules out `Dictionary<Point2D, ...>`, as profiling found out this op is taking 35% of entire frame time in my sample implementation :-(

*EDIT:* To stress out: I want to remove all fields OUTSIDE of given rect (kill unused cache)

The coordinates can take any int-values (they are used to cache [almost] infinite isometric 2D map tiles that are near camera in Unity).

The points will be always organized in rect-like structure (I can relax this requirement to always follow rect, actually I am using isometric projection).

The structure itself is used for caching tile-specific data (like tile-transitions)

Comment: Create your custom coords class, and make sure you override GetHashCode and provide an implementation that doesn't cause conflicts.

Comment: @Nick I've done that - still removing range of keys outside of given rect is a bottleneck of Dictionary

Comment: Since you are working with 2d spacial data anyway, why can't you use something like a QuadTree instead of a Dictionary, then there would be no hashing.  https://gamedevelopment.tutsplus.com/tutorials/quick-tip-use-quadtrees-to-detect-likely-collisions-in-2d-space--gamedev-374

Comment: @Kyle How can it help, when coords are uniformly spaced (and the world is infinite)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT:  Updated with outcome of discussion

You can use a sparse, static matrix for each "Chunk" in the cache and a cursor to represent the current viewport.  You can then either use modulus math or a Quad tree to access each chunk, depending on the specific use case.

Old Answer:

If they are uniformly spaced, they why do you need to hash at all?  You could just use a matrix of objects with NULL where is the default value if nothing is cached there.

Since you are using objects, the array is actually just references under the hood, the memory footprint of the array wouldn't really be affected by the null values.

If you truly need it to be infinite, you nest the matrices with a Quad Tree and create some kind of "Chunk" system.

Comment: I actually thought about array, but then camera panning is very expensive operation (shifting array?)

Comment: Why would it be expensive if the array is sparce, just declare a sufficiently large array to fit your cache

Comment: This data collection is used to cache renderer-state for each tile (like type-transition), not to state tile itself :)

Comment: Okay, so my array goes 0x0 -> 25x25. Now what will happen if I pan camera 3 units left?

Comment: Can you be more detailed, I don't understand how those are related?

Comment: `TileCache [,] cache = new TileCache[25,25]; 

// populate cache with items from 0x0 to 25 x 25.

// Now camera moved, so new cache range is requested -3x0 to 22x25, keeping as many values from previous calculation as possible`

Comment: Your cache can be WAY bigger than your viewport.  Remember that you can declare an array without initializing all of the objects in it.

Comment: I don't believe it is possible on plain arrays without moving all values of array

Comment: I know; But it cannot be 4,000,000,000 x 4,000,000,000 and this is still the range of world :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187526/discussion-between-kyle-and-piotrk).

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you need: [RTree](https://github.com/enyim/RTree/blob/master/src/RTree/RTree.cs)

Comment: Nice! It does not have fast lookup (coords to given element) through... :-(